# Angular state management with multiple instance of same component

Tags: angular, state, angular-components

I am designing my first app using Angular and was reading on state management when the following scenario came to my mind, for which, I couldn't find an answer

I have a component A that can change its variable v1. The state of this app is saved lets say in a service which is used by all the components to get the updates. Now when we use multiple instances of the component A, the variable V1 could have different values with respect to the different instances. Now how does state management work? how do I read and write V1 from and into the state repository respectively. Don't we need to store the data for each instance separately? How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If you did, can you post your solution?